# How to convert std::vector<std::vector<double>> to Rcpp::Dataframe or Rcpp::NumericMatrix

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I have a `std::vector<std::vector<double>>` and I want to convert this into either a `Rcpp::DataFrame` or a `Rcpp::NumericMatrix`.

My current solution looks like this and it is far from ideal; it yields a list of numerics.

```
RcppExport SEXP Foo(...)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> result;

    /// ... Do some work.

    return Rcpp::wrap(result);
}
```

Considerations: The number of columns and rows will not be fixed. Between each run these can change. I mention this because lots of the solutions I've found so far involve knowing the columns at compile time.

If possible, I'd like the solution to be fully contained in c++; i.e. The R user should be able to call the function and not have to man handle the result into a dataframe or a matrix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Converting a `std::vector<std::vector<double>>` to a list is the best we can offer in general. A `DataFrame` requires that all columns have the same length.

You have to handle that yourself manually. Something like this to make a matrix:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> result ;
int nc = result.size(), nr = result[0].size() ;
NumericMatrix m( nr, nc ) ;
for( int j=0; j<nc; j++){
    std::vector<double>& result_j ;
    if( result_j.size() != nr ) stop( "incompatible size" ) ;
    for( int i=0; i<nr; i++){
        m(i,j) = result_j[i] ;
    }
}
```

Making a `DataFrame` directly is somewhat harder, I'd suggest first making a list and then convert this list to a `DataFrame` :

```
List list( nc ) ;
for( int j=0; j<nc; j++) list[j] = wrap( result[j].begin(), result[j].end() ) ;
DataFrame df = list ;
```

You might need setting the names of the list before you make it a data frame though.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. I went with the NumericMatrix solution you provided.